# Git push new project permission denied

Tags: git, permissions, repository, push, bitbucket

So I tried to create a new Project at bitbucket and Import my current stuff.

Step 1: Switch to your repository's directory

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
```

Step 2: Connect your existing repository to Bitbucket

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/KevinSpence/app.git
git push -u origin master
```

After

```
git push -u origin master
```

I got this error:

```
$ git push -u origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong, (it is not my first Project on bitbucket)

Comment: are you using a different computer than before?

Comment: @brad no it is excatly the same I think

Comment: I would still check for existing keys and update them on both ends. Sorry but thats the only thing I can think of that is causing issue. Dont know if this helps...https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have your ssh key setup correctly.
Follow this to setup an ssh key: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

As somebody else already commented, this page can help you troubleshoot further: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/permission-denied-publickey-302811860.html

If that still doesn't help, you might opt to add your remote to git using https instead of ssh. Bitbucket should have a drop-down under clone to pick between https and ssh